# modal popup works in codepen, not on site

Tags: javascript, jquery, popup

I've been working on a responsive modal popup window, that handles html text, and html5 videos. I created the following, and it works fine on codepen... 
https://codepen.io/jabbamonkey/pen/NYdZXq

However, when I plug it into my site (html, css, javascript), the code doesn't work. When I click the PLAY VIDEO button (under the round photo of the guy), it looks like the modal JavaScript is messing with my top navbar JavaScript ... but I can't see any conflict with the JavaScript. In CodePen, I see the modal popups ... but on my site, they don't work. I can't find the issue and need some help.

The site I am working on is at [http://www.amazingdg.com/_client/a/](http://www.amazingdg.com/_client/a/#)

The code is all on codepen, and my site shows all the other code. I'll include the code below as well...

Html:

```
<a href="#" class="modal-trigger" data-modal="modal-name1">Play Video</a>
 <div class="modal" id="modal-name1">
          <div class="modal-box">
            <video autoplay loop muted preload="auto" style="width:100% !important; height:auto !important;">
                <source src="video/video-home.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
                <!-- <source src="http://yourwebsite.com/your-video-file.ogg" type="video/ogg"/>
                <source src="http://yourwebsite.com/your-video-file.webm" type="video/webm"/> -->
            </video>
            <button class="close-modal">Close!</button>
          </div>
        </div>
```

CSS:

```
.modal,
.modal-box {
  z-index: 99999;
}

.modal { /* overlay*/
  display: none; 
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  background: rgb(0,0,0);
  background: rgba(0,0,0,.8);
  overflow: auto;
}

.modal-box { /* box with content */
  background:#FFF;
  position: relative;
  width: 80%;
  padding:20px;
  max-width: 920px;
  margin: 100px auto;
  animation-name: modalbox;
  animation-duration: .3s;
  animation-timing-function: ease-out;
}

/* Close Button */
.close-modal {
  text-align: right;
  cursor: pointer;
}

/* Animation */
@-webkit-keyframes modalbox {
  0% {
    top: -250px; 
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    top: 0; 
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

@keyframes modalbox {
  0% {
    top: -250px; 
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    top: 0; 
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

JavaScript:

```
//***************************//
// Menu Button        
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery('#nav-icon').click(function(){
        jQuery('#mainmenu').toggleClass('menuview');
        jQuery(this).toggleClass('open');
    });
}); 



//***************************//
// Slide Menu
$(function() {
  $(window).scroll(function() {
    var winTop = $(window).scrollTop();
    if (winTop >= 30) {
      $("#topbar").addClass("sticky-nav");
      $("#navdemo").addClass("navdemoon");
      $("#subnav1").addClass("submenudrop");
      $("#subnav2").addClass("submenudrop");
      $("#mainnav1").addClass("menudroppad");
      $("#mainnav2").addClass("menudroppad");
    } else {
      $("#topbar").removeClass("sticky-nav");
      $("#navdemo").removeClass("navdemoon");
      $("#subnav1").removeClass("submenudrop");
      $("#subnav2").removeClass("submenudrop");
      $("#mainnav1").removeClass("menudroppad");
      $("#mainnav2").removeClass("menudroppad");
    }
  })
})


//***************************//
// Video Popup Lightbox
$(".modal-trigger").click(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  dataModal = $(this).attr("data-modal");
  $("#" + dataModal).css({"display":"block"});
});

$(".close-modal, .modal-sandbox").click(function(){
  $(".modal").css({"display":"none"});
});


//***************************//
/* Video Preloader*/
var video = document.getElementById("featvideo");
var url = "../video/video-home.mp4";
var progressBar = document.getElementsByClassName('.progress-bar')[0];

var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.setRequestHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
xhr.open("GET", url, true);
xhr.responseType = "arraybuffer";
xhr.onload = function(oEvent) {
  var blob = new Blob([oEvent.target.response], {type: "video/mp4"});
  video.src = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
};
xhr.onprogress = function(oEvent){
  if(oEvent.lengthComputable) {
    var percentComplete = (oEvent.loaded/oEvent.total)*100;
    var completion = Math.round(percentComplete) + '%';
    progressBar.setAttribute('valuenow', completion);
    progressBar.style.width = completion + '%';
    progressBar.innerHtml = completion + '%';
  }
}
xhr.send();
```

Comment: on your site do you wrap your modal inside a position absolute container ?

Comment: 1. Check the console for errors 2. Put *all* of the jquery code in a single document.ready handler - your click handlers are outside one at the moment

Comment: What is the code supposed to do? Also `xhr.setRequestHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');` is not for you to set. Also why not use $.ajax???

Comment: Abdeslem, the model is inside the BODY, with no other divs around it.

Comment: mplungjan, the xhr. code that you mention is part of a video preloader (getting the video file from the server). I tried removing the entire preloading javascript, but the modal problems were still there.

Comment: Rory McCrossan, I pieced together the modal javascript from other places. I'm not really familiar with writing my own javascript code. Can you help me with how this is done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like the problem is that the click event isn't attached to the button. To make sure it works even if the button is not in the DOM when the page loads, you can do this:

```
$("body").on("click", ".modal-trigger", function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  dataModal = $(this).attr("data-modal");
  $("#" + dataModal).css({"display":"block"});
});
```

Also if you don't want the button to go back to the top of the page, change `href="#"` to `href="javascript:void(0)"`.

EDIT:

I see the problem on your site. You put the code into the header section, so you don't have any DOM elements yet. You need to move this line

```
<script src="http://www.amazingdg.com/_client/a/javascript/javascript.js"></script>
```

to the end of the `body`, to make sure every DOM element is loaded, so you can attach event handlers to them with JS... Another way to make it work to put ALL of your javascript inside the `$(document).ready` handler.

Comment: I tried it ... didn't work.  The javascript:void(0) is stopping the page from jumping to the page top ... but the other code didn't seem to do anything (still no popup)

Comment: If I copy this exact code to the console on the page, it works... Just try it. You need to go a bit deeper, make sure that jQuery is loaded, and that there are no other javascript errors stop executing this code.

Comment: Edited, and found the real solution, check it!

Comment: That worked ... popup now opens, but now the CSS is a bit messed up (the container box isn't wrapping around the video). Ug.

Comment: Just remove `position:absolute` from the `video` element.

Comment: You are awesome. Technically, I needed the position:absolute for the top feature video, but your guidance helped me clear that up. Thanks for everything!